# How do you properly merge two sorted arrays?

Tags: java, arrays, merge

What is the proper way to merge two sorted arrays? I am currently working on a short Java program to merge two already sorted arrays. Please find my code below.

```
public class Merge {

    // data
    private static int[] data;
    private int elements;

    // constructor
    public Merge()
    {
        data = new int[4];
        elements = 0;
    }

    // DoubleSize method doubles array size if needed
    public void DoubleSize()
    {
        int[] tmp = new int[2 * data.length];
        // transfer existing data
        for (int i = 0; i < elements; i++)
        {
            tmp[i]=data[i]; 
        }
        data = tmp;
    }

    // this methods adds to the end of an array 
    public void add(int val)    
    {
        if(elements >= data.length)
        {
            DoubleSize();
        }
        data[elements] = val;
        elements++;
    }

    // this method prints the array values
    public void print()
    {
        // for-loop to print valid data only
        for(int i = 0; i < elements; i++)
        {
            System.out.print(data[i] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    // this method gets a value given an index
    public int get(int loc)
    {
        return data[loc];
    }

    // set a value, given an index
    public void set(int loc, int value)
    {
        data[loc]= value;
    }

    // this method sorts the data in array in ascending order
    public void sort()
    {
        int[] tmp2 = new int[data.length];
        for(int i = 0;i < data.length; i++)
        {
            int loc = this.min();
            tmp2[i] = this.get(loc);
            data[loc] = this.get(this.max())+1;
        }
        data = tmp2;
    }

    public int[] merge(int[] data2)
    {
        int[] data3 = new int[data.length + data2.length];
        int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0; 

        // Traverse both array 
        while (i < data.length && j < data2.length) 
        { 
            // Check if current element of first 
            // array is smaller than current element 
            // of second array. If yes, store first 
            // array element and increment first array 
            // index. Otherwise do same with second array 
            if(data[i] < data2[j]) { 
                data3[k] = data[i]; 
                i++;
            }
            else {
                data3[k] = data2[j]; 
                j++;
            }

        } 

        // Store remaining elements of first array 
        while (i < data.length) {
            data3[k] = data[i]; 
            i++;
            k++;
        }

        // Store remaining elements of second array 
        while (j < data2.length) {
            data3[k] = data2[j];
            j++;
            k++;
        }
        return data3;
    }

    // main method to test our previous methods
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Merge array = new Merge();

        // adding in numbers to sort 
        array.add(-7);
        array.add(2);
        array.add(4);
        array.add(9);
        array.add(13);
        array.print();  
        array.merge(new int[] {-9, 1, 6, 22});
        array.print();

    }
}
```

Currently the output is just:

> ```
> The following elements have been added to the array:
>
> -7 2 4 9 13 
>
> -7 2 4 9 13
> ```

I can't seem to figure out why this isn't working as intended. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Can you tell us what `array.print();` actually prints? That would make debugging a lot easier, as we don't need to run your code ourselves! Please use the [edit] function to amend that information. Thanks!

Comment: Hi there, I just added in the current output. Sorry about that!

Comment: You're discarding the array returned by `merge()`. Either use the return value directly, or have the method update the `data` field.

Comment: How can I have the method update the data field exactly?

Comment: It is good that you added the actual output of your code, but **don't** fix the errors in your code. This would invalidate any answer given to this question. Your question is meant to serve everyone coming here in the future. If your code doesn't contain errors, they will be very confused

Comment: Oh okay, got it! Sorry, I'm new to SO!

Comment: @user6072 Don't worry about it. Nobody coming to this platform is expected to understand how the site works right out of the box

Comment: @user6072 also consider accepting my answer if it solved your problem (by clicking the grey tick). It will show others that the problem has been solved. Also both you and I will get additional reputation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have quite a number of bugs in your code.

I will tackle them one by one, while only explaining them and not providing an actual full solution - as I suspect you are working on a homework problem.

```
public void DoubleSize()
```

#### Functional problems (preventing your code from running correctly)

- Your code doesn't compile. `this.min()` and `this.max()` in `public void sort()` are not defined.
- Your method `public int[] merge(int[] data2)` returns the merged array. Yet you never do anything with that array. Have that method not return anything, but instead set the newly created array to the member of the class (`data`).
- You are not incrementing your variable `k` in the first loop in `merge`. It is always `0`, meaning you always write to the same position in the array.
- You don't update the variable `elements` after merging
- In your main loop in `merge`, you are iterating `i` until `data.length`. Consider that this includes the end of the array, which is filled with `0`. Maybe you want to use another variable instead?
- After your main loop in `merge`, you are copying all remaining elements from `data`, but as we just said, they are all `0`. So skip that part entirely

Implementing all the things above will result in a working solution. I have tested it myself

#### Other problems (not the cause for the malfunction, but still important)

- Java naming conventions dictate that method names should be spelled with a lower case initial letter. This called "camelCase" (you used "CamelCase"). This is not the reason why your code is not working, but it's good practice.
- Your member `data` is declared static. Static members belong to classes, not to objects. You should make that member non-static!
- You don't strictly need a variable `k`, as `k == (i + j)` should always be `true`. Simplifying this will get rid of one of your problems in the first list!

Comment: Hi there, I updated my code to change the method to not return anything. i also set data = data3. In my while loops, I am incrementing my variables k and i, I think maybe I am not understand what you are referring to. I also was confused by your 4th point, if you don't mind explaining that.

Comment: @user6072 sorry, I had a few typos in my answer (and an outright error). Please see the current version of my answer

Comment: Hello! So i got rid of the sort method altogether because it is not needed for my problem. I also incremented k in the first loop in merge, and still am running into the same issue :/

Comment: @user6072 I found two more problems with your code. I added them to the answer. That should be all then

Comment: @user6072 And I restructured my answer

Comment: "You don't update the variable elements after merging": this is what i am having trouble understanding. What would I update the elements variable to?

"In your main loop in merge, you are iterating i until data.length. Consider that this includes the end of the array, which is filled with 0. Maybe you want to use another variable instead?": Could iterate i until elements -1?

Comment: @user6072 well, assume that your `Merge` object has 5 values. Then `elements == 5`, right? Then you merge in 3 more values, now `elements == 8` should be true. But it is still at `5`! So it grew in size. Your code needs to reflect that fact!

Comment: @user6072 with your second question, your guess was almost correct. iterate `i` while `i < elements` (and leave the other condition with `j` untouched).